# "Select" argument in R's data.table::fread

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread

I'm trying to read selected columns from a csv using fread(). I've found that I **can** use a vector of column numbers, but **not** with the column names. In regards to the "select" argument, the documentation just says "Vector of column names or numbers to keep, drop the rest." They also provide the example of

```
fread(data, select=c("A","D"))
```

Thus, why does my code throw a *subscript out of bounds* error? Here's the gist of my code, hopefully generalizable to other users:

```
test = data.frame(matrix(c(1:50),ncol = 5))
names(test) = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
write.table(test, file = "/Users/me/Desktop/test.txt", sep = ",")
fread("/Users/me/Desktop/test.txt", sep = ",", header = TRUE, select = c("A","B"))
```

Giving

```
Error in ans[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

However this gives the first column as well as the row number as a column:

```
fread("/Users/me/Desktop/test.txt", sep = ",", header = TRUE, select = c(1,2))
    1  1
1:  2  2
2:  3  3
3:  4  4
4:  5  5
5:  6  6
6:  7  7
7:  8  8
8:  9  9
9: 10 10
```

...And read.table() is able to uneventfully read the whole data set:

```
read.table("/Users/me/Desktop/test.txt", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
    A  B  C  D  E
1   1 11 21 31 41
2   2 12 22 32 42
3   3 13 23 33 43
4   4 14 24 34 44
5   5 15 25 35 45
6   6 16 26 36 46
7   7 17 27 37 47
8   8 18 28 38 48
9   9 19 29 39 49
10 10 20 30 40 50
```

Something is obviously going on with the rownames and the header, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I've tried with and without headers. The data set I'm using (not in this example) already has rownames, so re-writing it with rownames = FALSE isn't an option.

Comment: Sure. I can't share the data, but I'll put up an approximation.

Comment: just wondering, does it make sense to have `header=FALSE` but then select based on names?

Comment: So, how do you expect `fread` to know the column names are `A`, `B` or `C` if you tell it to actually ignore the column names?

Comment: Great points, and yes I've tried header=TRUE. Fwiw, header=FALSE doesn't work either. This is just the current version of *nonworking* code. I'm working on a reproducible example right now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having silly "empty file" errors with my test file, so in the mean time I'll remark that I looked at the data.table::fread source code and there's very little going on with the "select" argument. Might be an interesting thought experiment.

Comment: No, it's probably your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes your original data was not produced via `write.table()`, that you were given a file and are attempting to read it via `fread()` (which is also stated in the question).

---

I believe you are having this problem because of the row names in the file. I have yet to come up with a direct way to apply `fread()` to the data, but I think this work-around will be safe and won't cost you much in terms of efficiency. Here are the steps ...

1) Read the first line of the file with `scan()` and add an extra `""` element at the beginning.  This is to offset the header row to account for the row names in the file.

```
nm <- c("", scan("test.txt", "", nlines = 1, sep = ","))
```

2) Define the columns you want and find them in `nm`.  Instead of 1 and 4, the offset now gives us 2 and 5 and accounts for the row names.

```
sel <- nm %in% c("A", "D")
```

3) Read the file, starting at the second line (i.e. without the header), and use `sel` in the selection argument.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("test.txt", skip = 1, select = which(sel))
```

4) Now that we've read the data that we want, we can reset the column names.

```
setnames(dt, nm[sel])[]
#      A  D
#  1:  1 31
#  2:  2 32
#  3:  3 33
#  4:  4 34
#  5:  5 35
#  6:  6 36
#  7:  7 37
#  8:  8 38
#  9:  9 39
# 10: 10 40
```

If the example you give is a good representation of the actual data, I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows why you always need to check carefully the format of the file you are producing. There are some differences between `read.table` and `fread`; here the issue comes from the row names and how they are written by `write.table`. As always, reading carefully the doc (`?write.table`) helps a lot.

`write.table` by default writes the row names. But here is how:

```
filename<-"somefilename.txt"
write.table(test, file = filename, sep = ",")
readLines(filename,2)
#[1] "\"A\",\"B\",\"C\",\"D\",\"E\"" 
#"\"1\",1,11,21,31,41"
```

I read the first two lines of the produced file. Reading them carefully, you can see that this is not a "standard" CSV. Why? Because the header has a 4 commas while the "data" lines 5. For a standard CSV, you should put a comma *before* the first column name. This is achieved by adding `col.names=NA` in `write.table`:

```
write.table(test, file = filename, sep = ",", col.names=NA)
#now works
fread(filename, sep = ",", header = TRUE, select = c("A","B"))
```

You can check and see that now a comma as the first character of the file appears. Alternatively, you can avoid to write the row names putting `row.names=FALSE` in `write.table`, but this is not always possible, since some times they are meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(data.table)
library(readr)

# save mtcars as CSV w/o row names or column names

write_csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv", col_names=FALSE)

# read in the same file with fread but since we tell it
# to not use a header, we have to specify the column names
# the way fread will create them otherwise you get your error

fread("mtcars.csv", header=FALSE, select=c("V1", "V4"))

##      V1  V4
## 1: 21.0 110
## 2: 21.0 110
## 3: 22.8  93
## 4: 21.4 110
## 5: 18.7 175
## 6: 18.1 105

# try again, this time keeping column names in the 
# data file
write.csv(mtcars, file = "mtcars.csv", row.names=FALSE)

# now read it back in and select based on column names
# I picked different columns
head(fread("mtcars.csv", select=c("mpg", "qsec")))

##     mpg  qsec
## 1: 21.0 16.46
## 2: 21.0 17.02
## 3: 22.8 18.61
## 4: 21.4 19.44
## 5: 18.7 17.02
## 6: 18.1 20.2
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not in your fread, it's in your write.table. 
By default it writes the names of each row in the first column. Have a look at the file written.

Try this: (explicity NOT writing the row.names)

```
write.table(test, file = "/Users/me/Desktop/test.txt", 
            sep = ",", row.names=FALSE)
```

Then do your fread(). It will work.

Comment: Note Nancy's last sentence, in the version edited 2 hours before you posted your answer: "The data set I'm using (not in this example) already has rownames, so re-writing it with rownames = FALSE isn't an option."